# Some websites give timeout only in my pc once and a while

Tags: wireless-networking, networking

I have two websites hosted in mediatemple and once in a while (about one or two twices a day and during about 10 minutes) the websites are giving timeout, including Media Temple Home page (www.mediatemple.net), but others websites are working.

But then when I access using a proxy tool or my PDA all the websites are up and running.

I've also disabled the firewall and the problem stays the same.

It's my computer? What can I do? Can anyone help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Luís

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some routing problems. Is it working by others on the same provider? Are you using the same internet connection with your PDA?

Comment: Hi schöppi. My PDA is not using the same internet connection. Doesn't tried that. Only google and some news websites of my country that I rarely go. And after deleting all the cache. I'll try jquery.com if it happens again.

Comment: Happen again now. jQuery and jQuery UI are working. :)

Comment: As @schöppi stated. It is most likely a routing issue. Some router between you and their servers went down. Your pda probably uses a different route.